Initial positions and velocities for the three-body problem
I have made a simulation of the three-body problem, it follows the euler's method of solving differential equations. I have tried some initial positions and velocities of the bodies and have observed many different configurations. But what all the simulations share is, the bodies either get separated and fly off to infinity or two bodies remain in orbit with each other and the other one flies off to infinity. Therefore, I did some research and got to know about some symmetric solutions which are stable. But when I tried those, the bodies seemed to stable for a very short amount of time and after a while, they fly off to infinity. Here is one symmetric solution which gets unstable soon. The link is of ScreePal.com: -
https://screenpal.com/content/video/cZhZn9VLGgP
You can clearly see that after two orbits, the blue body shoots off to infiity whereas the other two bodies remain in orbit with each other. Please ignore why the bodies are vibrating when they are moving slowly, it is just because of the slight change in coordinates that the system can't figure out properly. Note that bodies have equal masses.
Here is the simulation with initial positions for the figure 8 problem, which does not at all looks like a figure 8: -
https://screenpal.com/content/video/cZhZewVLG5c
What I am asking for is the initial positions and velocities of the three bodies that can atleast prevent them from shooting off to infinity. I know figuring out the initial positions and velocities can be a bit tedious but I have tried the figure-8 solution, the solution showed earlier and many other too, but all those systems show the same behaviour.
Also note that there is no problem with the time step ($dt$) being too large. I have set it to one second which I think is enough, this time step might be awful for human time scale problem like predicting the motion of a double pendulum, but for predicting the motion of planets, this time scale is actually very accurate.

no problem with the time step Making $dt$ small doesn’t necessarily help, since the finite precision of floating-point arithmetic on computers means that roundoff errors will just accumulate faster because you’re taking more “steps”. I have no idea whether this is the actual cause of your problem. It’s possible that your numerical integration algorithm is too naïve. You haven’t even mentioned which one you’re using. If it’s the Euler algorithm, you need to use a better one.

Yes, I have used the Euler's method. Now I have mentioned it in the question too, thank you for the suggestion.

I suggest that you try the two-body problem with your code and see whether you even get closed ellipses, and whether energy is conserved.

What Ghoster said. Euler integration can't even make a closed orbit for a mildly eccentric orbit like Mars, as a one-body problem (the Sun fixed at the origin). Start simple, with a better integrator, with the one or two body problem, in two dimensions. When you have that working properly, then go to three dimensions, and more bodies.

BTW, many readers will not watch your videos on a site that they have to sign into. You should include screenshots or simple GIF anim diagrams (limit of 2 MB).

I see you're using Java. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78501789 If you can read Python, my code using synchronised Leapfrog integration (aka Velocity Verlet) may be helpful. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48477/16685 Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/50048/16685

Thanks for the suggestions. And I want to clarify that the data was produced by c++ and the simulation has been simulated in python, frankly, I know nothing about Java. I am a python and a c++ coder.

Oops. Yes, that SO question is clearly tagged C++. I don't know where I got Java from...

Three body problems are very difficult to simulate because they are generally chaotic.  As you researched, there are a few stable orbits, the figure 8 being one such orbit.
As mentioned on Wikipedia:

The [figure eight] solution has been shown numerically to be stable for small perturbations of the mass and orbital parameters, which makes it possible that such orbits could be observed in the physical universe.

That wording ("small perturbations") suggests that the region of stability is quite small.  This suggests that the stability is going to be very dependent on your integration algorithm.  In the comments you mentioned you are using Euler's method.  That's probably not a good enough integration method to be able to model results in that small region of stability.  Integrators for problems like these tend to be higher order Runge-Kutta methods, or symplectic integrators.
As an interesting nuance, small $dt$ does not always bring better results.  It brings better results up until your changes get to be so small that adding up all the numeric imprecisions starts to dominate your error.  For every problem and every integration method, there's a sweet spot that balances these effects.

Thanks Cort Ammon. I should as well try the Runge-Kutta method, and Olay with the simulation with varying dts.

Before investigating the influence of initial conditions, here some suggestions about numerical methods for ODEs.

Avoid using self-implemented Euler methods because:

explicit Euler method is not stable: it's likely that the energy of the numerical model system increases even in conservative systems
implicit Euler method is too dissipative: it's likely that the energy of the numerical model decreases rapidly even in conservative systems
they're first order
they're not variable-step method that are efficient methods that can help accuracy, reducing the timestep only when needed (qualitatively only when derivatives become large and large changes in short period of time may occur)


Do not re-invent the wheel! Rely on mathematical packages available nowadays for all programming languages. They're validated and efficiently implemented and with lots of functions that allow you to change the numerical scheme changing one line of code:

as an example, use a Runge-Kutta method, up to 4-5$^{th}$ order with adaptive timestep.




Thanks for the answer, basics.
